# Is there a function to lock a cell that already has data validation, based on the contents of a different cell?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet I use to keep track of desired loot within a game. In column C, I use data validation to create a drop down menu of the items available. Column F contains a drop down menu with the options "Yes" and "No" to determine if that player has received the item yet.

I am trying to make it so that when "Yes" is selected, it will essentially "lock" the corresponding cell in column C so that it can no longer be edited. If this is not possible, I at least want it to remove the drop down menu from that cell (but leave the text contents in the cell, so we can see what was selected). If I needed to use checkboxes instead of a drop-down menu for "Yes" and "No", I am open to that.

Example of the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B8F1XFjPvABRuO2sVYvBU0UBzY2H-ftU7NU85AakiPE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Google Apps Script for this. You can open it via Tools > Scriptediter. 
Paste this and it should do the trick. It removes the data validation and only keeps the selected value. If you change something in column F, it removes the validation in C. Etc.

Hope it helps.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var actRange = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  var actRow = actRange.getRow();
  var value = sheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  var range = e.range;
  var rangeColumn = range.getColumn();

  var columnsToCheck = [6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26]

  if (value == "Yes" &&  rangeColumn == 6)
  {
    sheet.getRange(actRow, 3).setDataValidation(null)
  }

  else if (value == "Yes" &&  rangeColumn == 10)
  {
    sheet.getRange(actRow, 7).setDataValidation(null)
  }

  else if (value == "Yes" &&  rangeColumn == 14)
  {
    sheet.getRange(actRow, 11).setDataValidation(null)
  }

  else if (value == "Yes" &&  rangeColumn == 18)
  {
    sheet.getRange(actRow, 15).setDataValidation(null)
  }

  else if (value == "Yes" &&  rangeColumn == 22)
  {
    sheet.getRange(actRow, 19).setDataValidation(null)
  }

   else if (value == "Yes" &&  rangeColumn == 26)
  {
    sheet.getRange(actRow, 23).setDataValidation(null)
  }

}
```

Comment: When I try to run this, it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 9, file "Code")". I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: You don't have to run the script manually. That will indeed run into the error that you got.
It's an 'on edit' script, which means it runs every time you edit something in your spreadsheet

Comment: I tried it in your spreadsheet and it seems to work. So give it a try and change a dropdown into a 'Yes'! 
I also undid the change I made so no worries there :)

Comment: Ahh, I see now. When I select "Yes" in column "F", it then removes the data validation from Column F. However, what I'm trying to do is when I select "Yes" in column "F", I want it to remove the data validation from Column "C". How would I edit this script to do that?

Comment: It's now changed to only apply to the corresponding column. So if you put a Yes in column F, it removes the data validation in Column C. If you do that in Column J, it removes the validation in Column G etc etc. 
I took the liberty to change it already in your script, should work like this now

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help! You can mark my answer as the correct one and give it a like